# Send Data of Json Array with multiple objects

Tags: android, mysql

```
 JSONArray jsonArray = jo.getJSONArray("products_list");
                        productList = new ArrayList<>();
                        String ProductName = null;
                        String ProductQTY = null;
                        String ProductCost = null;
                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject jsonObject2 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            ProductName = jsonObject2.getString("product_name");
                            ProductQTY = jsonObject2.getString("product_quantity");
                            ProductCost = jsonObject2.getString("product_cost");
                        }

                        Pname = ProductName;
                        Pqty = ProductQTY;
                        Pcost = ProductCost;



 SaveProduct(BillNo, Pname, Pqty, Pcost);
```

and the corresponding json is-

```
"gstin_no": "987654321",
"products_list": [

    {

        "product_name": "himalaya shampoo",
        "product_quantity": "20",
        "product_cost": "100*product_quantity"
    },


    {

        "product_name": "almonds",
        "product_quantity": "2",
        "product_cost": "400*product_quantity"
    },

    {

        "product_name": "Rin Soap",
        "product_quantity": "20",
        "product_cost": "10*product_quantity"
    },

    {

        "product_name": "himalaya shampoo",
        "product_quantity": "20",
        "product_cost": "100*product_quantity"
    }]
```

I am trying to make an android app where i am scanning QR code and getting output in json format i want to send an array with multiple objects into Mysql database but when i am sending value to database i am value of last object is inserting in database . how can i insert all the objects of array into database??

How can I insert all the objects to the Mysql databse.

Comment: value of only last object `Pname = ProductName`, don't you think it some should be somehow used inside loop!

Comment: I have tried to do that also . I put it inside the loop but still not working properly @Pavneet_Singh

Comment: i said somehow so as obvious you are only keeping reference to one object but need all so think!

Answer (score 2):

you are calling `SaveProduct(BillNo, Pname, Pqty, Pcost);`
    after the for loop.so you are getting last index values.Make sure your method should be inside the loop.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject jsonObject2 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                ProductName = jsonObject2.getString("product_name");
                                ProductQTY = jsonObject2.getString("product_quantity");
                                ProductCost = jsonObject2.getString("product_cost");

SaveProduct(BillNo, ProductName, ProductQTY, ProductCost);
                            }
```

Comment: what is this save product in which uh are storing values?

Comment: @Sunny I replied to above question.he defined a method like SaveProduct() and save his product from json.

Comment: sir can uh help me out with my problem ?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60255626/how-to-send-recyclerview-list-to-server-using-volley

Comment: @Sunny I have seen your code.Actually you have 2 elements in your arraylist.So the indexes will be 0 and 1.but in your for loop you are trying getting the elements at 2nd position.your loop will be like this for(int i=0;i<movieList.size();i++)

Comment: i got your reply now i want to send that data into paremters like multiple objects have same data moviename,adds,no soo i want to send whole object to my server such that it stores the objects in that place automatically.

Comment: Everything in your code is fine.did u get any error like java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in your Logcat.Because your loop is surrounded with try,catch block so remove = in your for loop and it will work fine

Answer (score 0):

So you need to make save call on your loop (json array length).

```
    String BillNo = jo.optString("gstin_no");
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject jsonObject2 = jsonArray.optJSONObject(i);
        String ProductName = jsonObject2.optString("product_name");
        String ProductQTY = jsonObject2.optString("product_quantity");
        String ProductCost = jsonObject2.optString("product_cost");

        SaveProduct(BillNo, ProductName, ProductQTY, ProductCost);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest [Gson Library](https://github.com/google/gson) for better readable code

First, add this to your dependencies

```
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2
```

Second, create your product model class

```
public class Product {
  private String product_name;
  private String product_quantity;
  private String product_cost;
}
```

just change your code with these lines

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Type listType = new TypeToken<List<Product>>() {}.getType();
List<Product> productsList = new Gson().fromJson(jsonArray, listType);
```

then you can save productsList in database better code with a few lines and better performance