# how to send Recyclerview list to Server Using Volley

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-volley

I have created a Project in which i have acustom alertdialog box with 3 edit text and one button. On button Click it add my data to Recyclerview successfully and it's working fine.

Now i want to post the recyclerview data to server using volley Post method can any one help me out how can i do it i just need a idea how to send data of recyclerview(list of my Recyclerview) to server. I want to Post full list of objects in array to server.

what should i send to my parameters so that i Successful post the recyclerview data to my server.

I have Reached Almost there but i want all objects in my same ARRAY LIST DATA But i am getting Different Array List with different object(need All object in one Array list)

Need Output Like

```
 [{
    "movie_name":"trter",
    "movies_Add":"hgjhj90",
    "movie_no":"8787878787"
    }
    {
    "movie_name":"trter",
    "movies_Add":"hgjhj90",
    "movie_no":"8787878787"
    }
    {
    "movie_name":"trter",
    "movies_Add":"hgjhj90",
    "movie_no":"8787878787"
    }
    ]
```

Code of

```
 JSONArray movieArray = new JSONArray();
                for (int i = 0; i <= movieList.size(); i++) {
                    JSONObject movieObject = new JSONObject();
                    try {
                        movieObject.put("movie_name", "" + member_name);
                        movieObject.put("movies_Add", "" + member_adds);
                        movieObject.put("movie_no", "" + member_contacts);
                        movieArray.put(movieObject);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                String jsonStr = movieArray.toString();

                Log.i("jsonobj12", String.valueOf(movieArray));
                Log.i("jsonobj123", String.valueOf(movieList1.size()));
```

Log Data

```
2020-02-14 09:49:54.283 17587-17587/com.example.raid I/jsonobj12: [{"movie_name":"trter","movies_Add":"hgjhj90","movie_no":"8787878787"}]
2020-02-14 09:49:54.283 17587-17587/com.example.raid I/jsonobj123: 1
2020-02-14 09:50:03.381 17587-17587/com.example.raid I/jsonobj12: [{"movie_name":"tertre","movies_Add":"hgvjnbk99090","movie_no":"7687687868"}]
2020-02-14 09:50:03.381 17587-17587/com.example.raid I/jsonobj123: 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few problems in your code I want to point out, maybe one of is fixing your problem. Identifying the real problem is hard, because you did not provide enough information:

1. This loop `for (int i = 0; i <= movieList.size(); i++) {` iterates one time too often. Let's say your movieList has 3 elements, your loop will iterate for each i in (0,1,2,3) but your list only has the indices (0,1,2) as Arrays/Lists start with index 0. So you should use `i < movieList.size()` here.
2. Are you sure you are adding the right items to your movieObject? `movieObject.put("movie_name", "" + member_name);` uses the variable *member_name* which is not updated within your loop, you probably need to use `movieList.get(i).member_name` or similar (please provide more information what exactly the movieList looks like). Same applies for the following two lines
3. In your log you use `movieList1` but in your loop you use `movieList` are you sure both lists are the same?

Comment: Got Your Ans thanku it worked for me now if i want to post data to my server within paremeters i know how to send my arraylist to server but i want to send same data in objects like its given in my postman.

Comment: {
                   
                    "Movie_name": "API sadf",
                    "Movie_add": "test",
                    "Movie_no": "test"
                  
                },
                {
                   
                    "Movie_name": "API MEMBER3",
                    "Movie_add": "test",
                    "Movie_no": "teta"
             },
this is my postman view i want to save all 3 values every time to object in front of thids movie_name and all can uh please help me out with this too.?

Comment: Your "need output like" section in your question shows "[" and "]" characters at the beginning and the end. This indicates a JSONArray. So do I understand it right you only want the three JSONObjects {...},{...},{...} so they are not wrapped in an array? If yes, I don't think this is possible, because it's not valid JSON Syntax. You probably have access to your server, so why not change your server to accept an JSONArray of JSONObjects containing your movies?

Comment: my server is accepting jsonArray which has multiple objects and i got your reply as a working ans thank you for your reply but now i am asking that i have to send 3 parameters in that object in which every 3 views like movie name,adds,no. will be auto generated and in that our data will be stored so i am asking how to send my multiple objects in parameters?

Comment: Sorry, I'm still not sure what you're trying to achieve, can you please give a concrete example?

Comment: [{
"movie_name":"abc",
"movie_ads":gfhfh12,
 "movie_no":"KG"
             },{"movie_name":"abc",
"movie_ads":gfhfh12,
 "movie_no":"KG"
             },     ]

Comment: And what exactly does not work?
Maybe again have a look at the second point of my solution above

Comment: this is my postman response if i enter data in post man now i want to send this array list to my server in parameters in which my data will be automatically stored to my server in respective locations movie_name,movie_ads,movie_no.

Comment: Ah okay, please have a look at this: https://developer.android.com/training/volley there is a great tutorial how to use it. If you need help, I would recommend opening a new question. If my answer above answered your initial one, please mark this solution as accepted

Comment: Sir ur code helped me out but when i am sending my array list of objects to server but i am getting error in this for null object

D/ressssssoo: {"success":4,"message":"Exception! Please Try AgainSystem.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.\r\n   at WebAPI.Controllers.RaidController.<Post>d__c6.MoveNext()"}

Comment: I don't think this error is related to the original question. Are you sure this error isn't thrown somewhere else in your code?